# How to identify substrings in the order of the string?

Tags: python

I have a list of sentences as below.

```
sentences = ['data mining is the process of discovering patterns in large data sets involving methods at the intersection of machine learning statistics and database systems', 'data mining is an interdisciplinary subfield of computer science and statistics with an overall goal to extract information from a data set and transform the information into a comprehensible structure for further use','data mining is the analysis step of the knowledge discovery in databases process or kdd']
```

I also have a set of selected concepts.

```
selected_concepts = ['machine learning','patterns','data mining','methods','database systems','interdisciplinary subfield','knowledege discovery','databases process','information','process']
```

Now I want to select the concepts in `seleceted_concepts` from `sentences` in the order of the sentence.

i.e. my output should be as follows.

```
output = [['data mining','process','patterns','methods','machine learning','database systems'],['data mining','interdisciplinary subfield','information'],['data mining','knowledge discovery','databases process']]
```

I could extract the concepts in the sentences as follows.

```
output = []
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence_tokens = []
    for item in selected_concepts:
        if item in sentence:
             sentence_tokens.append(item)
    output.append(sentence_tokens)
```

However, I have troubles of organising the extracted concepts accoridng to sentence order. Is there any easy way of doing it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `.find()` method to find the position of the substring and then sort by that value. For example:

```
output = []
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence_tokens = []
    for item in selected_concepts:
        index = sentence.find(item)
        if index >= 0:
             sentence_tokens.append((index, item))
    sentence_tokens = [e[1] for e in sorted(sentence_tokens, key=lambda x: x[0])]
    output.append(sentence_tokens)
```

Comment: Hi, I am wondering if this can be changed to search concepts at word level. i.e if my `concepts` list have the following: `concepts = ['d','dat', 'data', 'data mining']` it will give me all of them in the output for the sentence `data mining is good`. Instead I only want `data mining` to be extracted. Can you please tell me what part needs to be changed as I tried to do it with `sentence.split()`. But still could not find a way.

Comment: This is not an easy problem to solve. You can append spaces around your `sentence` and also your `item` as a primitive method of doing that but it won't work if the sentence have punctuation characters. One way is to replace all non-letter characters in the sentence with spaces and then try the method I suggest.

Comment: I have already pre-processed them. So, they do not have any punctuation marks. And all the letters are lowercased. What did you mean by `append spaces around your sentence and item`? I did not get it.

Comment: So to catch only exact matches you could append and prepend space (`" "`) characters to `item`, but that would fail at the boundaries (i.e. the start and end of the sentence). To circumvent that, you should pad your _sentence_ with spaces too.

Comment: On a second thought, that would also match `data` before `data mining`. You might need to construct a tree-like structure that define interdependencies between match words. As I said, it's not an easy problem to solve, especially in a comment box. You can try posting a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sure, I will post it as a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use .find() and .insert() instead.
Something like:

```
output = []
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence_tokens = []
    for item in selected_concepts:
        pos = sentence.find(item)
        if pos != -1:
             sentence_tokens.insert(pos, item)
    output.append(sentence_tokens)
```

The only problem would be overlap in the selected_concepts. For example, 'databases process' and 'process'. In this case, they would end up in the opposite of the order they are in in selected_concepts. You could potentially fix this with the following:

```
output = []
selected_concepts_multiplier = len(selected_concepts)
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence_tokens = []
    for k,item in selected_concepts:
        pos = sentence.find(item)
        if pos != -1:
             sentence_tokens.insert((selected_concepts_multiplier * pos) + k, item)
    output.append(sentence_tokens)
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a built in statement called "in". it can check is there any string in other string.

```
sentences = [
'data mining is the process of discovering patterns in large data sets involving methods at the intersection of machine learning statistics and database systems',
'data mining is an interdisciplinary subfield of computer science and statistics with an overall goal to extract information from a data set and transform the information into a comprehensible structure for further use',
'data mining is the analysis step of the knowledge discovery in databases process or kdd'
]

selected_concepts = [
 'machine learning',
 'patterns',
 'data mining',
 'methods','database systems',
 'interdisciplinary subfield','knowledege discovery',
 'databases process',
 'information',
 'process'
 ]

output = [] #prepare the output
for s in sentences: #now lets check each sentences
    output.append(list()) #add a list to output, so it will become multidimensional list
    for c in selected_concepts: #check all selected_concepts
        if c in s: #if there a selected concept in a sentence
            output[-1].append(c) #then add the selected concept to the last list in output

print(output)
```

Comment: `output = [[]]`

Comment: @PunyCode yes it will become [[]] because in loop, there is "output.append(list())"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that regular expressions search text in order, left to right, and disallow overlaps:

```
import re
concept_re = re.compile(r'\b(?:' +
    '|'.join(re.escape(concept) for concept in selected_concepts) + r')\b')
output = [match
        for sentence in sentences for match in concept_re.findall(sentence)]

output
# => ['data mining', 'process', 'patterns', 'methods', 'machine learning', 'database systems', 'data mining', 'interdisciplinary subfield', 'information', 'information', 'data mining', 'databases process']
```

This should also be faster than searching for concepts individually, since the algorithm regexps use is more efficient for this, as well as being completely implemented in low-level code.

There is one difference though - if a concept repeats itself within one sentence, your code will only give one appearance per sentence, while this code outputs them all. If this is a meaningful difference, it is rather easy to dedupe a list.

Answer (score 1):

Here I used a simple re.findall method if the pattern is matched in the string then re.findall will give the output as that matched pattern otherwise it will return an empty list based on that I wrote this code

```
import re

selected_concepts = ['machine learning','patterns','data mining','methods','database systems','interdisciplinary subfield','knowledege discovery','databases process','information','process']

sentences = ['data mining is the process of discovering patterns in large data sets involving methods at the intersection of machine learning statistics and database systems', 'data mining is an interdisciplinary subfield of computer science and statistics with an overall goal to extract information from a data set and transform the information into a comprehensible structure for further use','data mining is the analysis step of the knowledge discovery in databases process or kdd']

output = []

for sentence in sentences:
    matched_concepts = []
    for selected_concept in selected_concepts:
        if re.findall(selected_concept, sentence):
            matched_concepts.append(selected_concept)
    output.append(matched_concepts)
print output
```

Output:

```
[['machine learning', 'patterns', 'data mining', 'methods', 'database systems', 'process'], ['data mining', 'interdisciplinary subfield', 'information'], ['data mining', 'databases process', 'process']]
```